# Indexing error only present in for loop. KeyError: "None of [ 'column names' dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, keyerror

I am having a weird error that only happens inside of a for loop. I am trying to use a for loop to index certain columns of survey data out of a massive csv spit out by psychopy after an experiment. Here is my code:

```
    rootdir = '/Users/soph99/Desktop/feartags_fork/surveys/data'
for dir, subdir, datafiles in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in datafiles:
        if 'ses-2_combined' in file and '.csv' in file:
            day2 = pd.read_csv(f'{dir}/{file}')
            pcl = day2[['PCL_part_3_question_number','PCL_part_3_question_text','part_3_slider.response']]
            pcl = pcl.dropna(axis=0)
            pcl = pcl.set_index('PCL_part_3_question_number')
            pcl.to_csv(f'PCL_data_{file}')
```

It is giving me the following error:

```
`KeyError: "None of [Index(['PCL_part_3_question_number', 'PCL_part_3_question_text',\n       'part_3_slider.response'],\n      dtype='object')] are in the [columns]
```

I then went in and attempted to run this code on one individual file, so I nixed the loop:

```
day2 = pd.read_csv('sub-FT023/sub-FT023_ses-2_combined_2021_Oct_01_1759.csv')
pcl = day2[['PCL_part_3_question_number','PCL_part_3_question_text','part_3_slider.response']] #double brackets because I am indexing a list
pcl = pcl.dropna(axis=0)
pcl = pcl.set_index('PCL_part_3_question_number')
pcl.to_csv('PCL_data_sub-FT023_ses-2_combined_2021_Oct_01_1759.csv')
```

And lo and behold, it worked. I don't know why it is telling me that the columns are not present in the loop, but then when I run the same code on one file, it works and spits out a beautiful csv with all my desired columns. The whole point of the loop is that I don't have to go back in and copy and paste the filename for each of the 30 files I'm trying to extract data from lmao. Help please!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This might be a dumb question, but are you sure that all the `ses-2_combined` csv files in your root directory actually do have all those columns? One crude but effective debug thing I'd try: in the loop, print `dir` and `file`, and also print `day2.columns`

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. Thank you for the debugging tip though, I will definitely do that to make sure. The thing is that there are tons and tons and tons of columns so it will be a bit messy...